# How to configure webpack to build only required assets to run the Angular 5 app?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular5

I have an **Angular 5**. When I run

`ng build --prod --named-chunks --aot`

It created all of these contents

```
[development a85a7dc] Initial dist subtree commit
410 files changed, 99342 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 dist/3rdpartylicenses.txt
create mode 100644 dist/Simple-Line-Icons.00ce23caac2c875bcc6d.svg
create mode 100644 dist/Simple-Line-Icons.0bbfc705e37a927ce2ae.woff
create mode 100644 dist/Simple-Line-Icons.6ac7320f709ffd2784b4.woff2
create mode 100644 dist/Simple-Line-Icons.b2892aa62b0fb2c21c8d.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/Simple-Line-Icons.dacd16c9a3d2cb61b472.eot
create mode 100644 dist/admin-single.module.282a79d845b5fcb1320d.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/admin.module.bcfe40696537046418a5.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/animate.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/blue-dark.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/blue.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/default-dark.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/default.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/green-dark.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/green.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/megna-dark.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/megna.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/purple-dark.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/purple.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/red-dark.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/colors/red.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/form.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/icons/font-awesome/old/css/font-awesome.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/icons/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/icons/themify-icons/themify-icons.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/spinners.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/css/style.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/alert.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/alert2.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/alert3.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/alert4.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/alert5.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/alert6.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/alert7.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/model.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/model2.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/alert/model3.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/error-bg.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/login-register.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/megamenubg.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/profile-bg.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/socialbg.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/user-bg.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/user-info.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/background/weatherbg.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/big/img1.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/big/img2.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/big/img3.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/big/img4.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/big/img5.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/big/img6.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/browser/chrome-logo.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/browser/firefox-logo.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/browser/internet-logo.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/browser/opera-logo.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/browser/photoshop.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/browser/safari-logo.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/browser/sketch.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/custom-select.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/document/colors.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/document/sidebar.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/document/template-strucutre.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/favicon.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/gallery/chair.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/gallery/chair2.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/gallery/chair3.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/gallery/chair4.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/icon/danger.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/icon/success.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/icon/warning.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/iproject_logo.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/logo-icon.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/logo-light-icon.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/logo-light-text.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/tooltip/Euclid.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/tooltip/shape1.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/tooltip/shape2.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/tooltip/shape3.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/tooltip/tooltip1.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/tooltip/tooltip2.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/tooltip/tooltip3.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/1.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/2.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/3.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/4.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/5.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/6.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/7.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/8.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/d1.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/d2.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/d3.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/d4.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/d5.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/images/users/profile.png
create mode 100644 dist/assets/prepros-6.config
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/app.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/blue-dark.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/default-dark.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/default.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/green-dark.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/green.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/megna-dark.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/megna.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/purple-dark.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/purple.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/red-dark.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/colors/red.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/grid.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/fonts/FontAwesome.otf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/animated.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/bordered-pulled.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/core.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/fixed-width.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/icons.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/larger.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/list.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/mixins.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/path.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/rotated-flipped.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/screen-reader.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/stacked.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/variables.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/.bower.json
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/.gitignore
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/.npmignore
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/HELP-US-OUT.txt
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/bower.json
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/css/font-awesome.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/css/font-awesome.min.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/fonts/FontAwesome.otf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-old.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/animated.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/bordered-pulled.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/core.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/extras.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/fixed-width.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/font-awesome.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/icons.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/larger.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/list.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/mixins.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/path.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/rotated-flipped.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/spinning.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/stacked.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/less/variables.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_animated.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_bordered-pulled.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_core.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_extras.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_fixed-width.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_icons.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_larger.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_list.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_mixins.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_path.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_rotated-flipped.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_spinning.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_stacked.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/_variables.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/old/scss/font-awesome.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_animated.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_bordered-pulled.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_core.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_fixed-width.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_icons.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_larger.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_list.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_mixins.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_path.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_rotated-flipped.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_screen-reader.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_stacked.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-arrows-10.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-arrows-10.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-arrows-10.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-arrows-10.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-10.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-10.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-10.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-10.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-elaboration-10.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-elaboration-10.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-elaboration-10.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-basic-elaboration-10.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-ecommerce-10.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-ecommerce-10.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-ecommerce-10.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-ecommerce-10.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-music-10.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-music-10.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-music-10.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-music-10.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-software-10.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-software-10.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-software-10.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-software-10.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-weather-10.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-weather-10.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-weather-10.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/fonts/linea-weather-10.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/linea-icons/linea.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons-variables.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons-wind.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons-wind.min.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.eot
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.svg
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.woff
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.woff2
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-beaufort.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-day.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-direction.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-misc.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-moon.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-neutral.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-night.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-time.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/css/variables-wind-names.css
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-beaufort.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-day.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-direction.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-misc.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-moon-aliases.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-moon.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-neutral.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-night.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-time.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-wind-aliases.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-wind-degrees.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-classes/classes-wind.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-beaufort.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-day.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-direction.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-misc.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-moon.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-neutral.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-night.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-time.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/icon-variables/variables-wind-names.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/mappings/wi-forecast-io.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/mappings/wi-owm.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/mappings/wi-wmo4680.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/mappings/wi-yahoo.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/weather-icons-classes.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/weather-icons-core.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/weather-icons-variables.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/weather-icons-wind.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/weather-icons-wind.min.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/weather-icons.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/less/weather-icons.min.less
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-classes/classes-beaufort.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-beaufort.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-day.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-direction.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-misc.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-moon.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-neutral.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-night.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-time.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/icon-variables/variables-wind-names.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/mappings/wi-forecast-io.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/mappings/wi-owm.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/mappings/wi-wmo4680.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/mappings/wi-yahoo.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/weather-icons-classes.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/weather-icons-core.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/weather-icons-variables.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/weather-icons-wind.min.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/weather-icons-wind.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/weather-icons.min.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/icons/weather-icons/sass/weather-icons.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/material.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/pages.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/prepros-6.config
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/responsive.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/sidebar.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/style.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/variable.scss
create mode 100644 dist/assets/scss/widgets.scss
create mode 100644 dist/common.77f48d57fa4108d9e1f0.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/company-single.module.dc3a19b95bc8b3caefe1.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/company.module.50afa3db79fff54da3e4.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/custom-select.33d0b67c047e466b46c4.png
create mode 100644 dist/dashboard.module.c5788978326b7896adc2.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/error-bg.5df682a513bde1494964.jpg
create mode 100644 dist/error.module.e02aae2eb90729885869.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/favicon.ico
create mode 100644 dist/feature-single.module.fb466648b0e8f28b2018.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/feature.module.5e2dbddf9491d7d69a36.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/fontawesome-webfont.674f50d287a8c48dc19b.eot
create mode 100644 dist/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg
create mode 100644 dist/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2
create mode 100644 dist/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff
create mode 100644 dist/home.module.59eabc03605ddcaa9795.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/index.html
create mode 100644 dist/inline.060fb46eecd2fb5efeb0.bundle.js
create mode 100644 dist/linea-arrows-10.4e2921ae2aa6ab286dca.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/linea-arrows-10.839102e05032bae37b07.svg
create mode 100644 dist/linea-arrows-10.9b287297a8d930c35c32.eot
create mode 100644 dist/linea-basic-10.177764eadf43efc393eb.svg
create mode 100644 dist/linea-basic-10.61f3a8a387a64abfc053.woff
create mode 100644 dist/linea-basic-10.e4de528c00da0c081906.eot
create mode 100644 dist/linea-basic-10.e6763f008205c55db623.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/linea-basic-elaboration-10.3759629be32bb8b55b21.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/linea-basic-elaboration-10.7193d8c51aea93b5f575.eot
create mode 100644 dist/linea-basic-elaboration-10.b1a9c3a92d7fe46449a6.svg
create mode 100644 dist/linea-ecommerce-10.86d8ba2ca6a7c6fe4442.svg
create mode 100644 dist/linea-ecommerce-10.e8892174d7f87530f38e.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/linea-ecommerce-10.ffd2088eabba9bda4af6.eot
create mode 100644 dist/linea-music-10.83767d2d18790bbcd939.svg
create mode 100644 dist/linea-music-10.a7dcedf1c8fb3ca79944.eot
create mode 100644 dist/linea-software-10.6cfc5077a8ac9e581ef5.svg
create mode 100644 dist/linea-software-10.8fe30102fca386ab297c.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/linea-software-10.b5b4a545328f3eee2789.eot
create mode 100644 dist/linea-weather-10.2a4ea9471689e35ecbb6.svg
create mode 100644 dist/linea-weather-10.7129dca4faddeb4beaf9.eot
create mode 100644 dist/linea-weather-10.eef9b7d7918436513bec.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/login.module.9a3b7555ae8bac70f66c.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/main.0b8caf51bf4915680bc9.bundle.js
create mode 100644 dist/materialdesignicons-webfont.2cfc2e0d57d974050530.svg
create mode 100644 dist/materialdesignicons-webfont.4fed03f1e0fb21693813.woff
create mode 100644 dist/materialdesignicons-webfont.a65b9561e6b00796ee6a.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/materialdesignicons-webfont.b8695cc16b97f1bd9744.eot
create mode 100644 dist/materialdesignicons-webfont.cc3cf0bd5af9550e4d18.woff2
create mode 100644 dist/permission-single.module.6c939171bb2d72ff1cda.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/permission.module.dfd0fe3edfde893edbb5.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/polyfills.ef275552c4585b1ad229.bundle.js
create mode 100644 dist/profile.module.3af77100faf328035eef.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/role-single.module.c3c70a15b2f80651aee5.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/role.module.c2bc0dd349aaf794ecd8.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/scripts.af5f40859ee4079b006e.bundle.js
create mode 100644 dist/signup.module.8b4684f17e54c937e450.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/styles.b977fea2555c97c82655.bundle.css
create mode 100644 dist/themify.2c454669bdf3aebf32a1.eot
create mode 100644 dist/themify.9c8e96ecc7fa01e6ebcd.svg
create mode 100644 dist/themify.a1ecc3b826d01251eddd.woff
create mode 100644 dist/themify.e23a7dcaefbde4e74e26.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/user-single.module.a8a819ffbf2a76bab9dc.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/user.module.1e7fa8b32a54fddca3f0.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/verify.module.dafa471570888e13416e.chunk.js
create mode 100644 dist/weathericons-regular-webfont.1cd48d78f06d33973d9d.woff2
create mode 100644 dist/weathericons-regular-webfont.4618f0de2a818e7ad3fe.ttf
create mode 100644 dist/weathericons-regular-webfont.4b658767da6bd92ce2ad.eot
create mode 100644 dist/weathericons-regular-webfont.8cac70ebda3f23ce4721.woff
create mode 100644 dist/weathericons-regular-webfont.ecaf8b481729b18f6a84.svg
```

As you can see, there are so many things images, fonts, css, and even js.
I only used 20% of that.

I want to control what to build. Where should I configure that ?

How do I build my dist/ folder base on what I required to run my **Angular 5** app ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ng eject
```

This will dump a webpack-config file that you can use to modify your build

Comment: After running `ng eject --force` what elses I need to run ?

Comment: I see error : https://www.dropbox.com/s/aa9at9zl48ki0qf/%202018-02-02%20at%203.26.35%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: then check what happens on line 134 in webpack.config.js

Comment: So you run npm install as mentioned before you call "ng run build"